# Counting Restaurant Orders

Tags: python-3.x

I created a computer program which takes a list of names and dishes chosen. The program then counts how many dishes and which dish are ordered. The result is then returned from a function. The algorithm is currently a brute force O(N*M) where N is the number of dishes and M is the number of people. Below is the code.

```
def count_items(rows, orders):
    counted = []
    has_found = False
    
    for row, order in enumerate(orders):
        has_found = False 
        for col, count in enumerate(counted):
            if count[0] == order[1]:
                has_found = True 
                counted[col] = (order[1], counted[col][1] + 1)  
        if not has_found:
            counted.append((order[1], 1))
    return counted 
                

def test_count_matching():
    assert count_items(0, []) == []
    assert count_items(1, [("Bob", "apple")]) == [("apple", 1)]
    assert count_items(2, [("Bob", "apple"), ("John", "apple")]) == [( "apple", 2)]
    assert count_items(2, [("Bob", "apple"), ("Bob", "apple")]) == [("apple", 2)]
    assert count_items(2, [("Bob", "apple"), ("John", "pear")]) == [("apple", 1), ("pear", 1)] 
   
def tests():
    test_count_matching()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add PEP484 typehints
- Don't count things yourself when `Counter` exists and is more suitable for the task
- `rows` is ignored, so drop it from your arguments list
- Your assertions, main guard and function structure are pretty good; keep it up!

### Suggested

```py
from typing import Tuple, Iterable, Counter


def count_items(orders: Iterable[Tuple[str, str]]) -> Counter[str]:
    return Counter(order for user, order in orders)


def test_count_matching():
    assert count_items([]) == Counter()
    assert count_items([("Bob", "apple")]) == Counter({"apple": 1})
    assert count_items([("Bob", "apple"), ("John", "apple")]) == Counter({"apple": 2})
    assert count_items([("Bob", "apple"), ("Bob", "apple")]) == Counter({"apple": 2})
    assert count_items([("Bob", "apple"), ("John", "pear")]) == Counter({"apple": 1, "pear": 1})


def tests():
    test_count_matching()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests()
```

Comment: The counter's keys need to be the last part of the tuple and not include the person's name. The reason is that the kitchen knows the order and needs to know how many times to cook that dish to complete the order for a group of people.

Comment: @AkashPatel _The counter's keys need to be the last part of the tuple and not include the person's name_ - right... which is what's happening here.

Comment: Sorry, I think misinterpreted the order variable as having both.